# Java Eclipse won't print to console

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem with my Java eclipse. When I first start eclipse and run a program, it prints to console but after the first run, it stops printing to console. I need to restart my eclipse to print stuff onto my console again. There are no errors on my code.

Any tips on fixing this?

Comment: Please show us the code that works ones

Answer (score 0):

be aware that the Console view has an option to lock the scroll down of the messages... (maybe it is printing but you are not getting the scrolled)

[image]